# Drop indexing from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I wanted to drop indexes from 2 fields "title" and "cycle" from the table "Regions"

This is structure of my  table and the fields within it

```
SHOW COLUMNS from Regions
```

---

```
 +------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id         | int(10)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| first      | int(10)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| last       | int(10)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| title      | varchar(200) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| cycle      | varchar(45)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I wanted to drop indexing from  fields "title" and "cycle"

I tried this  :

```
DROP index  cycle  ON Regions
```

I also tried :

```
ALTER TABLE Regions drop index cycle
```

but it didnt work

Could anyone advise?

Thanks!

Comment: Which server are you working with? MySQL? PostgreSQL? MS SQL?

Comment: I am working mysql server.

Comment: Have a look at my answer, this should help you.

Comment: Please edit your question to include `SHOW CREATE TABLE Regions;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax was actually right. [`DROP INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-index.html) will remove the index from your column.

However, you have to use the name of the index, not the name of the column. The name you used, `cycle`, is actually the column name. To find out the name of the index, use the [`SHOW INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html) command:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM Regions
```

After you figured out the index name, you can delete it:

```
DROP INDEX name_of_your_index FROM Regions
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the names of the index? If they are the same as the field name this should work...

```
DROP INDEX `title` ON Regions;
```

Or this...

```
ALTER TABLE `Regions` DROP INDEX `title`;
```